# How can I change subtitle color, background or font used by iTunes?

Tags: itunes, subtitle

In iTunes subtitles background is black and font Courier New (and rather big). How can I change this preferences?

Answer (score -1):

A quick googling of [iTunes skin's](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=iTunes%20skins&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) yields quite a few results on changing the look and feel of iTunes. I don't know personally how to change individual aspects of iTunes though.

Comment: Thank you for response but i am searching for only subtitle preferences.